# How to perform an order logic in SSIS package for inserting value from source to destination by an oder of column being not null

Tags: ssis

I have 4 columns in source table.

**Source Table  : Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4**

Among those 4 columns from source table, I want to insert only 2 columns in the destination table.

**Destination table : has column A and Column B**

To insert value in Column A and Column B. Now i want to perform order operation in SSIS package.

So I want to have an oder logic in SSIS .

If there is a value in Column 1, then use that in Destination Column A and insert from column 1 value into Column A . So, if there is value in Column 1, then Column A in destination table will be inserted.

IF there is no value in Column 1, then check the Column 2 in the source table and if there is value in Column 2, insert that value in Column A.

Now suppose, Column 1 was null and Column 2 had value, Column 2 value will be inserted into column A in the destination table.

Now check the column 3 in source and see if there is value, if it has value then insert that value in Column B in Destination table. If there is no value in Column 3 then check column 4 from source.

So basically check in those 4 columns in the order (which is specified) and 1st value that we come across, use that in the destination Column A and Column B.

There is tricky part is there, so 1st not null value goes into the Destination column A and 2nd not null value goes into 2nd destination column B, how can i figure it out which one is 2nd not null value?

I guess we can do this in SQL but I want to do in SSIS package.

I will really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While you can probably make this work via Derived Columns, it's going to get messy. Something like this can be better expressed in a Script Component.

Add a Script Component into your Data Flow as a Transformation. In the Input Rows tab, select cols 1-4 as ReadOnly. In the Ouput tab, add 2 new columns to the Output buffer as Column A and Column B and be sure to set the data type to match cols 1-4. Back on the General tab, click Script.

Inside your `ProcessInputRow` method, you'll need to compute what is going to be assigned to A and B. The following code is approximate. If you need it pristine, comment and I'll get it fixed when I'm on a PC.

```
int firstNonNull = 0;
string colA = string.Empty;
string colB = string.Empty;

// Assign a value for colA and remember
// where we found it
if (!Row.Col1_IsNull)
{
    firstNonNull = 1;
    colA = Row.Col1;
}
else if (!Row.Col2_IsNull)
{
    firstNonNull = 2;
    colA = Row.Col2;
}
// Question does not address whether we will find
// non null values in 2 columns exactly
// assuming not
else if (!Row.Col3_IsNull)
{
    firstNonNull = 3;
    colA = Row.Col3;
}
else if (!Row.Col4_IsNull)
{
    firstNonNull = 4;
    colA = Row.Col4;
}

// Now to assign a value for B
// Assume that the next column after the first non null is populated
// otherwise, repeat above process
switch (firstnonNull)
{
    case 1:
        colB = Row.Col2;
        break;
    case 2:
        colB = Row.Col3;
        break;
    case 3:
        colB = Row.Col4;
        break;
    // Now what?

}
```

A more clever person could have popped all the values into a List or something and then found the first two non-empties or other means but this is pretty straight forward for maintenance.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Can you please post the original as like you said. Also I will be using source as OLEDB and then script component and then destination?

Comment: What's my "original" I don't see that in the text

Comment: sorry to make u confused. you said "The following code is approximate. If you need it pristine, comment and I'll get it fixed when I'm on a PC."

Comment: Have you tried it yet? It'll be a bit before I have some free time today

Comment: yes i did. I was confused little bit. Its not a problem. Whenever you have time.